Intervalos de fechas
Me encuentro con un problema al trabajar con un conjunto de datos en Python utilizando pandas. El conjunto de datos consta de registros en los que cada fila contiene un "sic" específico (identificador de políticas promocionales), junto con una "fecha de inicio" y una "fecha de finalización" para cada promoción activa. Mi principal reto surge al manejar las transiciones entre promociones solapadas y promociones singulares.
El problema es el siguiente: cuando se solapan varias promociones, necesito que la "fecha de finalización" de dichas promociones se extienda durante todo el último día del solapamiento. Sin embargo, al pasar de un periodo de promociones solapadas a un periodo con una sola promoción activa, es crucial que no haya ningún hueco ni solapamiento en las fechas. La fecha de inicio de la nueva promoción única debe coincidir exactamente con la fecha de finalización de las promociones anteriores, sin duplicar ni omitir ningún día.
He intentado ajustar las 'fechas finales' para evitar solapamientos o intervalos incorrectos utilizando el timedelta de Python, pero me cuesta conseguirlo de forma consistente, especialmente cuando cambia el número de promociones que se solapan. La lógica debe ajustar dinámicamente las fechas en función de si el siguiente intervalo comienza con una o varias promociones.
Mi código es el siguiente
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# Asumiendo que ya tienes el dataframe df_ap_sics
# Ordenar df_ap_sics por sic, fecha de inicio y fecha de fin
df_ap_sics = df_ap_sics.sort_values(by=["sic", "fecha inicio", "fecha fin"])

# Inicializar las listas para las nuevas filas
new_rows = []

# Iterar sobre los sics únicos
for sic in df_ap_sics["sic"].unique():
    # Obtener todas las filas para este sic
    sic_rows = df_ap_sics[df_ap_sics["sic"] == sic]
    
    # Crear un conjunto de todas las fechas únicas (inicio y fin)
    all_dates = sorted(set(sic_rows["fecha inicio"].tolist() + sic_rows["fecha fin"].tolist()))
    
    # Ajustar las fechas para manejar correctamente los intervalos
    for i in range(len(all_dates) - 1):
        start = all_dates[i]
        end = all_dates[i + 1]
        
        # Corrección para asegurar que la fecha de fin es el día anterior a la nueva fecha de inicio
        # Ajustamos este punto según si la siguiente fecha tiene más de una política
        current_promos = set(sic_rows[(sic_rows["fecha inicio"] <= start) & (sic_rows["fecha fin"] >= start)]["politica_promo"])
        next_promos = set(sic_rows[(sic_rows["fecha inicio"] <= end) & (sic_rows["fecha fin"] >= end)]["politica_promo"])

        # Si la fila actual tiene más de una política, extendemos la fecha fin hasta incluir el día completo
        if len(current_promos) > 1:
            end_adjusted = end - timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            end_adjusted = end - timedelta(days=2)

        # Si la siguiente fila tiene solo una política, ajustamos la fecha de inicio
        if len(next_promos) == 1:
            next_start_adjusted = end
        else:
            next_start_adjusted = end - timedelta(days=1)
        
        # Obtener todas las filas que se superponen con este intervalo ajustado
        overlapping_rows = sic_rows[(sic_rows["fecha inicio"] <= start) & (sic_rows["fecha fin"] >= end_adjusted)]
        
        # Crear una fila con las promociones únicas
        promos = set()
        for _, row in overlapping_rows.iterrows():
            if row["fecha inicio"] <= start and row["fecha fin"] >= end_adjusted:
                promos.add(row["politica_promo"])
        
        # Solo añadir fila si hay promociones
        if promos:
            new_rows.append({
                "sic": sic,
                "fecha inicio": start,
                "fecha fin": end_adjusted,
                "politica_promo": ", ".join(promos)
            })

# Crear un nuevo dataframe con las nuevas filas
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

# Mostrar el nuevo dataframe
new_df

Mi tabla original es:

y lo que yo esperaría obtener es:

pero el código me esta dando mal las fechas


Primero, diría que en orden para tener un [mcve], sería mejor que el código de tu ejemplo no asuma que ya tienes el DF, sino que incluya su construcción.  Luego, no veo en el código como pasas del texto "HOOK"  a "GANCHO", por lo que asumo que, o no es el código que estás usando, o no es el conjunto de datos.
